# How to get href id value in php?

Tags: php, html, get, href

I am learning php right now.

I have a anchor that shows the php value I want to pass. But the problem is, I can't get the said value.

Here is my anchor code in html:

```
<a href="#?pName='.$prodName.'">Add</a>
```

Here is the link that displays the value:

```
http://localhost/pphcompany/index.php#?pName=family1
```

Here is my php code to get the value of pName:

```
$prodName = $_GET['pName'];
```

But it's not working and returns an error that says:

```
Undefined pName
```

Please anyone could help me get that value?

Comment: show full code, is your html in php script.

Answer (score 0):

That `#` is killing your get. Everything behind # is not being parsed as a $_GET, but rather as a link to the same page's portion with that name. Edit your code to:

```
<a href="?pName='.$prodName.'">Add</a>
```

And you should be fine.

Comment: i tried removing the # but the page refreshing. all my input are lost

Comment: The part after `#` isn't sent to the server and doesn't actually make a difference to the `$_GET` value.

Comment: Yes, that's what is expected to happen when you navigate away to another url. Please can you explain what you want to achieve in your original post, which might also stop this question from being a duplicate?

Comment: I want to get that value to be displayed in a `popover`. but since the page is refreshing, the popover will not be displayed.

Comment: For that you should use javascript (or jquery) if you don't want the page to refresh, or submit the form and once submited display the popover. PHP works in this way: it is executed in the server and then the html file is sent to the browser. Once it is in the browser PHP is not executed any more except if you submit the page. So you cannot retrieve a value from an input and display in a popover with PHP, you need another technology (javascript) or submitting the form. For the latter you'd use an `<input type = "submit">`, for the former a link like this: `<a id = "addprod" href = "#">Add</a>`